# Как сделать поиск по title у постов Wordpress REST API?

Tags: wordpress, api, http, rest

как сделать поиск по заголовку в http запросе Wordpress Api, например...

Полная версия сайта - https://flutternerd.com.

Полные версии постов - flutternerd.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts   -   (JSON)

Есть пост

```
[
  {
    "id": 285,
    "link": "https://flutternerd.com/build-android-ios-app-for-wordpress-blog-with-flutter/",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Build Android &#038; IOS App For WordPress Blog with Flutter"
    }
}
]
```

что написать в поисковой строке, чтобы этот пост вывелся по слову Build(находится в title -> rendered)???
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, так сделать нельзя. Вы можете искать по постам, содержащим слово `Build` в любом месте (не только в заголовке):

```
https://flutternerd.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=build
```

или по точному значению слага

```
https://flutternerd.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=build-android-ios-app-for-wordpress-blog-with-flutter
```